# nor operator can't be used in filter cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of objects which contains date fields in my document, I want to match the object elements in the array using filter, I have a query similar to below

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: "test_key"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      testArray: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$testArray',
          as: 'item',
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$item.date1",
                  ISODate("2018-05-06 00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$item.date2",
                  ISODate("2018-06-08 00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It works well if I use a `$or` operator in the `$cond` operator, although I actually want to use `$nor` instead of `$or`, but the query reports the below error with `$nor`

```
Failed to execute script.

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$nor'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$nor'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

Is there any restrictions on the operator used within `$cond`?

Comment: It's not a restriction, it's just there is no such operator as `$nor`. The valid operators are `$and`, `$or`, and `$not`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#boolean-expression-operators Don't confuse query operators and expression operators.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for the explanation, I indeed confused query operators and expression operators. I think I should use or and not here to accomplish my task